# cat ~/.gemrc results in "no such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I just finished install Xcode, Homebrew, git, RVM and Ruby on a brand new MacBook Pro machine (following this [guide](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)). Next thing I wanted to do is install Rails (following this [guide](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html#gems)) but cat ~/.gemrc only gives me a "No such file or directory". Any ideas on what I may haven't done properly? Is there a way I can create this file manually - and is such a thing advised or not?

**EDIT:**

```
gem environment
```

gives this output

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-11-10 patchlevel 327) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/sebkomianos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/sebkomianos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/sebkomianos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-12
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/sebkomianos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
   - /Users/sebkomianos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

So I guess the configuration file exists somewhere and I only need to add

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

to it so I avoid the rdoc and ri on every gem installation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

copy-paste the following command:

```
$ echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" >> ~/.gemrc
```

This will do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 13):

There is no ~/.gemrc because you haven't modified any default yet.

If you for example add the RubyGems source with this command:

```
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org
```

You will find the ~/.gemrc file automatically created.

Answer (score 1):

you have to generate this file by yourself: All "~/.*rc " files are user generated. Their purpose is to place a configuration in them which fit you special needs. They are used at first place before any standard configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/gemrc`, it could also be there.

Any changes you make to your local `~/.gemrc` will take precidence

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to add the two lines, `install:...` and `update:...` to a file called `.gemrc` in your user home directory.  If the `.gemrc` file doesn't exist,  create it.

Comment: haha -- we're all trolling for quick and easy answers.  Three answers in 2 minutes, all saying the same thing.